# get time zone of historic date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

A business requirement of a project is as follows:

The user needs to view historic dates based on his local time zone. For now, we store two dates in the database: UTC and the local time. The user needs to view the date in the (historic) time zone.

Example:

> Database values: 2017-10-25T12:00:00 (UTC), 2017-10-25T09:00:00 (Date
>   of registration).

From these values, we want the user to view the date in his time zone.

> 2017-10-25T12:00:00 (UTC) to CEST (time zone offset +0200) =>
>   2017-10-25T14:00:00.

However, when the user views the same date on a date where summer time does not apply, the user will see 2017-10-25T13:00:00 because CET is +0100.

I'm looking for a way in which it is possible to get the offset from UTC for the user's locale on the UTC date.

In short: get the UTC offset for a historic date in the user's local time zone.

***EDIT: libraries like Moment.js and Moment_timezone.js are accepted!***

Comment: Why are you storing two values if you still need to convert UTC time to local? Date object should handle converting itself, so `new Date(Date.parse('2017-10-25T12:00:00'));` will return Date object that contains local time corresponding to 2017-10-25T12:00:00 UTC.

Comment: The two values are stored to meet business requirements. They want to have the two dates for reporting.

Comment: @Walk - careful with that.  The ECMAScript spec has changed a few times, so that might be considered local time, or might be considered UTC.  Adding a `Z` at the end will ensure it is parsed as UTC in all environments.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way in which it is possible to get the offset from UTC for the user's locale on the UTC date.

```
var dt = new Date("2017-10-25T12:00:00Z");
var offset = dt.getTimezoneOffset();
```

(note the `Z` at the end)

Though really, one wonders why you need the offset at all.  The local time is already represented by the `Date` object in `dt`.

If you want to do this with Moment, then you can do:

```
var m = moment("2017-10-25T12:00:00Z");
```

Or if you don't want to add the `Z` then create the Moment object like so:

```
var m = moment.utc("2017-10-25T12:00:00").local();
```

You can format the moment from there, or call `m.utcOffset()` if you like.

You don't need Moment-timezone, unless you intend to reflect some time zone other than the user's local time zone.

Comment: This solution won't work for changed time zones (Russia for example). Russia abolished summer time in 2014. This method is fine for dates after the abolishment, but every date before will be incorrect.

Comment: That's not exactly true.  In modern browsers, it should still return the correct historical time, as long as the data is available on the host OS.  However if you want to go back further than the host has (on Windows in particular) then you do need to bring your own data with moment-timezone.  Do you need an example of that?  Or are the moment-timezone docs sufficient?

Comment: Also note that the behavior you describe (of not honoring historical rules) was changed in the ECMAScript spec, in ES6/ES2015.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments. I think I got it by doing like so:

```
var oUTC = moment(new Date(2015, 7, 25, 12, 0, 0, 0));
var oRecordedDate = moment(new Date(2015, 7, 25, 13, 0, 0, 0));

//step 1: calculate historic offset with DB values
var iDBOffset = oUTC.diff(oRecordedDate);

//step 2: calculate historic offset from UTC in user's locale
var oHistoricDate = oUTC.clone().tz(moment.tz.guess());
var iHistoricOffset = Math.abs(oHistoricDate.utcOffset() * 60 * 1000);

//step 3: calculate total offset
var iTotalOffset = iDBOffset - iHistoricOffset;

//step 4: resulting date object
var oDate = new Date(oRecordedDate.valueOf() - iTotalOffset);
console.log(oDate.toString());
```